# Find nearest point using PostGIS

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis, knn

On PostgreSQL 12 with PostGIS extension, I have two tables defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
    id_a integer,
    id_b integer,    
    coord geometry,
);

CREATE INDEX table_a_coord_idx ON table_a USING gist (coord);

CREATE TABLE table_b (
    id_b integer,
    coord geometry,
);

CREATE INDEX table_b_coord_idx ON table_b USING gist (coord);
```

Both tables have around 3 millions entries. The `coord` columns contain only Point geometries. Values of `id_b` are initially null.

My goal is to find for each point in `table_a` the closest point from `table_b` and fill in the column `id_b`.
I wrote a small Python script to achieve this with an index-based KNN search:

```
import psycopg2 as pg

conn = pg.connect()
cur = conn.cursor()

cnt = 0
cur.execute('SELECT id_a, coord FROM table_a WHERE id_b IS NULL')
for row in cur.fetchall():
    cnt += 1
    cur.execute('SELECT id_b FROM table_b ORDER BY geom <-> %s LIMIT 1;', (row[1],))
    nearest_vertex = cur.fetchone()
    cur.execute('UPDATE table_a SET id_b=%s WHERE id_a=%s', (nearest_vertex[0], row[0]))
    if cnt % 1000 == 0:
        conn.commit()
conn.commit()
```

This code works. But it takes on average 0.6s to proceed one entry, thus it would take around three weeks to proceed all entries.

Does anybody know how to speed up this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processing records 1 by 1, in a loop, induces a lot of network traffic to the DB.
Instead, try to update all entries at once, in a single statement (which you can send from the pyton script if you wish).

```sql
UPDATE table_a 
SET id_b = (
  SELECT id_b 
  FROM table_b 
  ORDER BY table_b.geom <-> table_a.geom 
  LIMIT 1
)
WHERE id_b IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late, but my first shot would be to check query like this:

```
-- Find the nearest hospital to each school
-- that is within 3000 units of the school.
SELECT DISTINCT ON (s.gid) s.gid, s.school_name, s.geom, h.hospital_name
    FROM schools s
        LEFT JOIN hospitals h ON ST_DWithin(s.the_geom, h.geom, 3000)
    ORDER BY s.gid, ST_Distance(s.geom, h.geom);
```

It's from postgis manual http://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.0/ST_DWithin.html. Just be sure you have indexes on geometry columns and avoid to big radius. The bigger the radius the slower the query.